# NSRegularExpression returns only a single match

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I had written a regex for matching cell addresses like in a spreadsheet and tried to match input strings using NSRegularExpression's **matches(in string:, options:, range:)** method.

```
let input = "A:IV"
let regexStr = "(\\$?(([a-h]?[a-z])|i[a-v])([ \\t]*)(:([ \\t]*)\\$?(([a-h]?[a-z])|i[a-v])([ \\t]*))*(:([ \\t]*)\\$?(([a-h]?[a-z])|i[a-v])))"
let colRegex = try! NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: regexStr, options: .caseInsensitive)
let matches = colRegex.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))
for match in matches {
 print("Match >>>>", match)
}
```

This code prints only a single match **A:I** and does not match **A:IV**.
When I change the regex like this :

> (\\$?(i[a-v]|([a-h]?[a-z]))([ \\t]*)(:([ \\t]*)\\$?(i[a-v]|([a-h]?[a-z]))([ \\t]*))*(:([ \\t]*)\\$?(i[a-v]|([a-h]?[a-z]))))

The code prints a single match **A:IV** and not **A:I**. Even though matching the entire input string is my goal, I do not understand why there is no more than one match for any given input string. There seems to no option that negates this behaviour either.

Comment: It is easy to explain: regex never tests the same starting position twice. So, what is the answer you expect? Get both the substrings? Or explanation why the first regex matched a part of the expected match? And if the string is like `A:IV:B:V`? Note that `IV` is not matched right away because `[a-h]?[a-z]` matched earlier than the regex engine could test the char against `i[a-z]`, swapping the alternatives gives the desired match, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bnad4p/1).

Comment: The part I'm confused about is, does NSRegularExpression returns only full matches or partial matches also? In your example A:IV:B:V, it can be broken into smaller tokens which also satisfy the same regex, like B:V. Does NSRegularExpression's matches method not return all possible matches in an input string?

Comment: All of them, but *regex never tests the same starting position twice*. You can't *match* at the same time `AB` and `A` in `ABC`. You may capture them though.

Comment: That explains my problem in the question. But, in the example I mentioned in my comment above, B:V should have counted as a separate match, right? Appreciate your help.

Comment: That part of your question is unclear. What do you need to match? If just `<1-2 letter>:<1-2 letter>`  patterns see https://regex101.com/r/Hrncd2/2 (link edited)

Comment: Please write in plain English what text your regex must match. And an example string with exact expected output. Please edit the question

Comment: So, do you need help?